# AWS Cognito InvalidParameterException clientName must contain a scheme

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

The [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html#CognitoUserPools-CreateUserPoolClient-request-ClientName) shows that we can use custom name. However, it will throw the error "clientName must contain a scheme".

```
String userPoolId = "ap-northeast-1_XXXXXXXX"; //cens user
    String clientName = "clientName";

    AWSCognitoIdentityProvider provider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.defaultClient();

    CreateUserPoolClientRequest update = new CreateUserPoolClientRequest()
            .withUserPoolId(userPoolId)
            .withClientName(clientName)
            .withAllowedOAuthFlows(OAuthFlowType.Implicit)
            .withAllowedOAuthScopes("phone", "email", "openid");

    provider.createUserPoolClient(update);
```

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same "must contain a scheme" error today when attempting to provision a new Cognito UserPool + UserPoolClient via CloudFormation. It's a poorly worded error. What it *should* say is: "The URLs you provided for either the callback or logout URLs must contain a scheme, such as https."

Once I updated my URLs so that they started with https, the CloudFormation deploy was able to move beyond the error.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes.

Comment: I logged in just to say thank you for this